# Turn off Journaling in Sql Server/ T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ibm-midrange

I need to turn off journaling in Sql Server/T-SQL to write to a file/table in as400. I have found that you can do it in SQLite with Pragma. However, I have discovered that doesn't exist in T-SQL. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm confused... why would you need to turn of journaling in Sql Server in order to write to an AS400?

Comment: Why do you feel that you need to turn it off? What limitation do you think is preventing you from doing what you need to do?

Comment: The error that i got specifically in sql server is:

Comment: <table> not journaled, no authority to the journal, or the journal state is *STANDBY.  Files with an RI constraint action of CASCADE, SET NULL, or SET DEFAULT must be journaled to the same journal.

Comment: @Loganj99 That error isn't from SQL Server, it's from the AS400... how are you trying to write to the table in AS400?

Comment: Just insert into <table>(column1, column2)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to disable commitment control on the link.  Which provider are you using?

**.NET**

```
DefaultIsolationLevel=Chaos
```

**OLEDB (IBMDA400)**

```
Extended Properties="Default Isolation Level=NC;Auto Commit Mode=True"
```

**ODBC**

```
CommitMode=0
```

Comment: We are using IBMDASQL OLE DB.

Comment: We ended up having to create a ODBC connection instead of using IBMDASQL.

Comment: @Loganj99 : CommitMode=0, would be "Commit immediate (*NONE)", on the advanced server options dialogue for an iSeries ODBC configuration, which you get to by pushing the "Advanced" button on the "Server" tab, right?