# Error when insert through a link server from sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server, odbc

I'm trying to insert some data from a c# application to an AS400 server.I made a DSN in Control panel,Data Sources :

```
Data source name : Newissues
Description :iSeries Access for Windows ODBC data source
Connection type : use odbc access mode
```

In C# I used OdbcConnection .My connection string is :

```
DSN=newissues; UID=strUser; PWD=strPassword;DBQ=DBName; QueryTimeOut=0;
```

From C# I can open database and make select ,but when I try to insert or delete I received this message:

```
ERROR [HY000] [IBM][iSeries Access ODBC Driver][DB2 UDB]SQL7008 - test in DBName not valid for operation.
```

My insert command is :

```
INSERT INTO DBName.test VALUES('0730','  10230526')
```

I try also to insert data from sql server where i have a linked server but i receive the same message error:

```
insert openquery(MyLinkServer,'select "IACO","IAPOLNUM" from DBName .test WHERE 1=0') VALUES('0730','  10230526')
```

Error:

```
OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "MyLinkServer" returned message "[IBM]   [System i Access ODBC Driver][DB2 for i5/OS]SQL7008 - test in DBName not valid for operation.".
Msg 7343, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "MyLinkServer" could not INSERT INTO table "[MSDASQL]".
```

Can somebody help me to resolve this problem?
Thanks

Comment: See [this Stackoverflow Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14124119/linked-server-insert-update-and-delete-fails-with-unknown-provider-error). It may help you

Answer (score 2):

**[Here is the Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9040884/turn-off-journaling-in-sql-server-t-sql)**

Change your connection string and add the blow code

```
CommitMode=0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
using (iDB2Transaction db2Transaction = db2Command.Connection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.Chaos))
{
  db2Command.Transaction = db2Transaction;
  Update/Insert/Delete
}

db2Command = iDB2Command
```

Note: `IsolationLevel.Chaos` is not recommended, because on the IBM i this results in a transaction which autocommits, and cannot be rolled back. Try other values in the `IsolationLevel` enum if it's gonna work.

Answer (score 0):

If in doubt, google the error: http://www.querytool.com/help/876.htm

Error SQL7008 while updating a DB2 for iSeries table

When updating a DB2 for iSeries table you can get error

SQL7008 -(table) in (file) not valid for the operation

This occurs because the table you are trying to update is not being journalled, and your update is being run within a transaction.

There are a number of ways of resolving this problem:

- switch off Options > Run SQL > Safe Update Mode. When Safe Update mode is selected, AQT will run Updates and Deletes within a transaction.
- ensure Options > Technical Parameters > Auto Commit is checked.
- if you are using DB2/Connect, ensure that AutoCommit is set to Yes. This is configured with the DB2 Configuration Assistant.
- If you are using DB2 Client Access Express, set the Commit mode to Commit immediate (*NONE ). This is configured on the ODBC Configuration for your Datasource.

Did you try all these already?

Answer (score 0):

Don't you have to reference the schema for a full qualified insert?

```
INSERT INTO DBName.dbo.test VALUES('0730','  10230526')
```